# How to structure unstructured data

Tags: nlp, data-mining, structured-data

I am analysing tweets and have collected them in an unstructured format. What is the best way to structure this data so I can begin the data mining processes?
Somebody suggested using python packages such as spacy but not sure how to go about using this.

Comment: what do you mean "structure the data"? Please clarify this point

Comment: Please provide examples of the tweets and what you expect as structure so people can get a clue so they can try to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) it's crucial to choose the representation of the data and the design of the system based on the intended task, there is no generic method to represent text data which fits every application. This is not a simple technical problem, it's an important part of designing the system.

The simplest method to structure text data is to represent the sentence or document as a [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) (BoW), i.e. a set containing all the tokens in the sentence or document.  Such a set can be represented with One-Hot-Encoding (OHT) over the full vocabulary (all the words in all the documents) in order to obtain structured data (features). Many preprocessing variants can be applied: remove stop words, replace words with their lemma, filter out rare words, etc. (don't neglect them, these preprocessing options can have a huge impact on performance).

Despite their simplicity, BoW models usually preserve the semantic information of the document reasonably well. However they cannot handle any complex linguistic structure: negations, multiword expressions, etc.

Comment: what is the difference between structuring unstructured data and classifying them?

Comment: @Ooker "structuring" is not really a technical term, but it refers to representing the data in a structured way, i.e. as features. Once represented as features, the data can be classified or clustered, for instance.

Comment: Are they both belonged to the category of information extraction?

Comment: @Ooker 'information extraction' is a broad term, so why not. Mind that there is no very precise categorization of the concepts in data science (and concepts tend to evolve fast).

Comment: Why is that? I suppose those are basic terms and should be more stable?

Comment: @Ooker look at what [information extraction covers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction): it's very broad and vague, it goes from keyword extraction (but then, what is a keyword?) to extracting sophisticated semantic relations, and there can be many ways to represent semantic information. Additionally to the fact that data science is very recent compared to maths or physics, some of its concepts are philosophical concepts that philosophy itself doesn't define precisely. The blurry nature of concepts such as information, language, or even logic is the cause.